# Async MVVM - how to change NotifyTaskCompletion.Result

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

My question stems from [an article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) of Stephen Cleary.

Basically, there is a Label

```
<Label Content="{Binding UrlByteCount.Result}"/>
```

and it's set by viewmodel c.tor

```
UrlByteCount = new NotifyTaskCompletion<int>(
                MyStaticService.CountBytesInUrlAsync("http://www.example.com"));
```

So far so good.
Now I do a trivial change:

```
 UrlByteCount = new NotifyTaskCompletion<int>(MyStaticService.ImmediateSet(-1));
```

having defined

```
public static Task<int> ImmediateSet(int res)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    tcs.SetResult(res);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Obviously the label immediately shows -1.
Ok, then I add a button with viewmodel command binding, *because I want to set the label when I click the button*.

skipping all the ceremonial part (delegate command, etc.), the core function is again:

```
private void TestLogic()
{
    UrlByteCount = new NotifyTaskCompletion<int>( // FIX ME
        MyStaticService.CountBytesInUrlAsync("http://www.example.com")); // FIX ME
}
```

I'm perfectly aware that it *doesn't* work and that the label's content will remain -1, but I'm asking which is the best approach to fix this?

## Second part of the question.

Assuming you've already found a solution to the first part and the click on the button asynchronously changes the label's content (maintaining ui responsiveness), can you confirm if the following code is a consistent way to prevent "double clicking" (i.e. "multiple executions")?

```
private async void TestLogic()
{
    canRun = false;
    ((DelegateCommand)TestCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    await FoundASolution();
    canRun = true;
    ((DelegateCommand)TestCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}

private async Task<int> FoundASolution()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    return 21;
}
```

Comment: Why it doesn't work? If you raise property changed event in setter of UrlByteCount, it should work fine.

Comment: @Evk I assumed it, because the binding is to "UrlByteCount.Result" and not to "UrlByteCount", so I thought it was not clean to do UrlByteCount = new ... Doesn't it ruin the pointer to .Result? Btw, yes I see that it does work

Comment: No, when you assign new value to UrlByteCount, binding knows it has changed (assuming of course you raise property changed event), even if binding path is UrlByteCount.Whatever1.Whatever2...

Comment: @Evk OK, so please answer the question. Thank you!

Comment: Why the downvote now? If you are downvoting my question because you think that it is important to raise property changed on the UrlByteCount, there is no need to do that. It's much more standard to bind to a regular string property and it does work. => look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36959353/6250137) (and also at my [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322150/review-the-mechanism-of-downvoting-questions) question, if hasn't be deleted)

Comment: I've saved a [pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B08U5MBXVHxLYVJ3NXZKSEUzWEk) with my meta post they have deleted

Comment: Most likely downvoter does not even receive notifications about your comments. Now only I receive them, but I did not downvote, so can't help. But you should not worry too much about someone downvoted you -take it easy.

Comment: @Evk I know you didn't, of course. I'm leaving, so unfortunately they'll delete my upvote for you, but your answer will remain marked as such. I think the downvoter got my message: async-await is just syntactic sugar while continuation is the more functional concept (more in my [blog](https://giuliohome.wordpress.com/2015/05/03/the-best-of-threading-with-delegates)). You see from the above pdf that Hans Passant, Jon Skeet, etc... have nothing better to do on Sunday than delete my meta-post. in Italian there is a saying "mirror for larks" to describe things like SO voting mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work fine assuming you raise property changed event in your `UrlByteCount` setter. The fact that you bind to `UrlByteCount.Result` does not mean binding will not refresh when you only change `UrlByteCount` - it will.

As for your second part - it's ok to disable button via making `Command.CanExecute` false and notifying about this via `Command.CanExecuteChanged` event, before starting long running operation. Just ensure you enable it back again even if operation fails with exception (so wrap inside try-finally block). You may want to notify user about error and allow him to fix it (or just wait a bit, if error is network failure for example), and retry operation, which won't be possible in your case - button will stay disabled in case of error.